# Length of chord in circle - Which property

Tags: geometry, circles

> > In the figure AB=4 , BC=6 , AC=5 and AD=6 what is length of DE ? Ans=9
> >     [image]

I know there must be some property here that would solve this problem instantly but I cant figure it out any suggestions ?
Edit:
Since the two triangles are similar there corresponding sides will be equal in ratio , however I am still getting the wrong answer

```
BA   CA   BC
4    5    6
AE   6    DE
```

$$AE = \frac{24}{5}$$
and $$DE = \frac{36}{5}$$

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You're applying the wrong similarity transform (a rotation instead of the reflection that's the actual similarity transform) and so getting the wrong cross ratios.  You have AC:BC::AD:DE, (5:6::6:?) but in fact it's AB:BC::AD:DE (4:6::6:?).

Comment: One way to see why the symmetry should be reflection and not rotation is to consider moving A 'north' towards the top of the circle; then AC obviously shrinks, but on the other triangle the edge that shrinks is AE, not AD - so the similarity must be between ABC and ADE (note orientation), not ABC and AED.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the [inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle_theorem#Theorem).

**Edit**: I guess it's time to expand this answer a bit. The inscribed angle theorem guarantees that the angles $\angle CBE$ and $\angle CDE$ are equal, as well as the angles $\angle BCD$ and $\angle BED$. Also, the angle $\angle CAB$ is obviously equal to the angle $\angle EAD$. Therefore the triangles $\triangle AED$ and $\triangle ACB$ are similar. This means that the ratios of the lengths of respective edges should be equal or:

$$\frac{|AE|}{|AC|}=\frac{|AD|}{|AB|}=\frac{|ED|}{|CB|} \; .$$

This means that the length of edge $ED$ must be $9$.

Comment: I know C and E share the same arc. But i cant figure how they help in determining DE ?

Comment: The triangles $\triangle ACB$ and $\triangle AED$ are similar because of that.

Comment: How is DE=9 if the two triangles are congruent ?

Comment: I meant similar, not congruent. Sorry for that.

Comment: Do I have to calculate the angles in triangle ABC ?

Comment: No, completely unnecessary.

Comment: I still dont see how the fact that the two triangles are similar helps to determine line DE

Comment: Well, what do you know about similar triangles?

Comment: If the two triangles are similar then their angles will be similar

Comment: What do you know about the ratios of their respective sides?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Corresponding sides of similar triangles are in same ratio

Comment: Rajeshwar, if two triangles are similar then their angles will be *equal*.